# Kurento : unable to create meeting

Tags: kurento

I am working on customized version of group call application. everything was working fine but suddenly I was unable to create/join a meeting.

On java side the console was struck at `Join Room: Participant testuser trying to join room meeting1`

and in kurento logs there was a warning message: `Worker threads locked. Spawning a new one.` I got this warning message two times.

I looked into the kms-core source code, it seems that worker thread is not `alive`

Is there any specific reason why the thread is not alive and are there any limit on how many maximum worker threads can be created ?

**Edit 1:**

I have changed the sequence of releasing the `customfilter` when the user leaves the meeting in `UserSession.java` `close()` method.

I am not getting this error today, but I a, getting the following errors in media server log file which are causing segmentation fault.

**Error 1:**

```
GStreamer-CRITICAL **: gst_mini_object_unlock: assertion 'GST_MINI_OBJECT_IS_LOCKABLE (object)' failed

(kurento-media-server:20224): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: gst_mini_object_unref: assertion 'mini_object->refcount > 0' failed

* Error in `/usr/bin/kurento-media-server': corrupted double-linked list: 0x00007f22b91767f0 *
```

**Error 2:**

```
GLib-ERROR **: /build/glib2.0-ajuDY6/glib2.0-2.46.1/./glib/gmem.c:100: failed to allocate 1348147596301458710 bytes
```

**Error 3:**

```
[31;1mSegmentation fault[0m (thread [33;1m139806617499840[0m, pid [33;1m1588[0m)
Stack trace:
[34;1m[gst_mini_object_copy][0m
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstreamer-1.5.so.0[32;1m:0x69D95[0m
[34;1m[kurento::module::vadcustomfilter::VADCustomFilterImpl::busMessage(_GstMessage*)][0m
```

Answer (score 2):

This indicates a deathlock on the mediaserver. In fact it seems that you have all the threads dispatching requests locked, that is why requests are not replied. Depending on the version and on the operations you performed the solution (work around) could be different.

You should file a bug on [kurento bugtracker](https://github.com/Kurento/bugtracker) including the kms log.

**Edit:**

About the segmentation fault, it seems to be caused bu the custom filter you are adding, please try to fix in order to avoid the error. It can be also possible that the dead lock is caused by this filter.

Comment: do you think that the issue might be not closing the socket connection properly after user leaves the room ?

Comment: Don't know without more info, but can be one of the reasons.

Comment: hi, I have edited the question can you please take a look at it

Comment: @SagarPilkhwal I've added the possible reasons of the problem to my answer, please check